# How to insert data into ms access db using text boxes?

Tags: vb.net

The code I'm using:

```
   Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\songs.accdb"
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [Songs] ([Song], [Artist], [Number]) VALUES (@Song, @Artist, @Number)"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Song", txtsong.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", txtartist.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", txtnumber.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
        End Using
        myconnection.Close()
    End Using
```

I have no idea what the problem is when I execute nothing happens and no records get inserted into the data base? any idea what's wrong?
P.S: I know it's a noob question and probably asked before sorry beforehand

Comment: How do you know nothing is inserted - how do you check?  `Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will return the number of rows affected.  If it is non zero, the query ran

Comment: @Plutonix I tried adding the code line you suggested but I'm getting nothing

Comment: I have just an extra note, you don't have to dispose "cmd" while you are using "Using" statement.

Comment: that code just tells you if the query worked.  I dont know what "getting nothing" means in this context.  Was it zero or a number like 1?   It is very, very likely a case covered by the dupe

Comment: @Plutonix getting nothing means nothing is happening when I click the button. but I think I figured it out thanks to the question you flagged I'm just going to stop using |DataDirectory|

Comment: You were supposed to look at the value of rows in debug.  It will tell you if the query executed or not.